# Error:(29, 0) Plugin with id 'com.google.gms.google-services' not found Android

Tags: android, firebase, admob

I have tried many solutions at stackoverflow but none worked for me.
When i sync the project it gives `Error:(2, 0) Plugin with id 'com.google.gms.google-services' not found`

As the documentation said (add the plugin at the end) i did the same. Added the plugin at the end.
`apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`

Any Solution? I followed [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start) link. Did the same as it said but there is Error.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.radioaudio.motivationalaudios"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.4.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Do you have the Google Repository installed, via your SDK Manager?

Comment: Have you added the classpath in the other gradle file?

Comment: @TimCastelijns no i haven't. It was not mentioned in the documentation. What classpath do i have to add?

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes it is installed

Comment: It is mentioned, in the getting started/setting up guide that is linked there

Comment: The needed classpath is in the [Firebase Setup Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#add_the_sdk)

Comment: @akkk, according to firebase create tutorial, you should add this into your parent build.gradle file: 
`buildscript {
    dependencies {
        // Add this line
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}`